# Why I am not able to see the the webpage after hosting it in github?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

Why I am not able to see the the webpage after hosting it in github? It's just showing a url with the name in same as in Readme but does't redirect
anywhere.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBLF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You GitHub Pages is working as expected. The only file in the repository is the README, so that is the only file built on Pages.

If you wanted to build a Pages site at myportifolio.github.io, you'd have to make a new GitHub account under the username myportifolio.

Answer (score 0):

By default, github displays the "readme.md" file.
And, your repo doesn't have anything to show in particular!

Try adding a dummy ".html" file and then open the website. If GitHub can't find anything to display it will display the "readme.md" file.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your html file to index.html (The file you want to run first). Then it will work

Answer (score -1):

**Make sure you follow the steps mentioned below-**

1. index.html is your root file.
2. You have changed your Github repo name at least one or two times,refresh the page & visit the page after a few minutes.

Comment: These steps worked for me always.